# Getting empty list of (objects)teams in jsp page from a simple class

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

I have an jsp page in which I am trying to get list of teams(class objects) in jsp to show some data regarding teams but problem is that list getting to me on jsp is empty and I don't know why it is empty, I tried to search it on internet but could not find the solution, I also debugged my jsp page so finding the empty list.

here is my jsp code

```
`<%@include file="index.html" %>
<%@page import="java.util.List,java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="Models.Team" %>
<%@page import="Controller.HockeyLeagueInitialization"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<% 
HockeyLeagueInitialization hli = new HockeyLeagueInitialization();
List<Team> teams = (ArrayList<Team>) hli.getTeamList();

%>



<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="margin-left: 0%">
                        <% for (int i = 0; i < teams.size(); i++) {
                                Team currentTeam = teams.get(i);

                        %>
                        <li><a href="#"> <%= currentTeam.getTeamName()%></a></li>
                            <% }%>
                    </ul>`
```

and here is my function that return list

```
public List<Team> getTeamList() {

    String selectAllTeams = "select * from team;";
    List<Team> listOfTeam = new ArrayList<Team>();

    try {
        stmt = new DBInitialization().getStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(selectAllTeams);

        while (rs.next()) {
            listOfTeam.add(new Team(rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("name")));
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return listOfTeam;
}
```

Comment: Well first i would make sure your `ResultSet` is actually getting filled with something.

Comment: Thank you for reply, I check it manually , it is working

Comment: @3kings,Sir, are you there?

Comment: hey my actual problem is that when I try to run it on main it run fine but when on serve it says at the back-end that no suitable driver found, why it 's not running on server even I have added mysql-connector to project

Comment: This line resolved my problem    `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`

Comment: Thank you @3kings